# How to split an object in two?

Tags: javascript

Given this object:

```
var json={
  list:{
    c1:"BTC",
    c2:"ETH",
    c3:"DOGE",
    c4:"LTC",
    c5:"BSV",
    c6:"XRB",
    c7:"SRB",
    c8:"WAVE",
    c9:"LINK",
    c10:"EOS"
  }
}
```

I need to divide the list in two parts.

The first part has the first 5 elements and the 2nd part contains the remaining elements. So total will be 10 elements in both parts.

How can I do that with JavaScript?

Comment: Are you looking to split the object in half? Or into groups of 5 properties?

Comment: you can iterate over an object's properties with the "for...in" construct. If that's not enough to get you there, post what code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `json.list` into a list of entries. e.g

```
[["c1", "BTC"], ["c2", "ETH"], ...]
```

Then reduce that into two lists: the first with 5 entries and the second with the rest of them. You can then convert the two list of entries into objects again.

```js
const partition = x =>
  [x]
    .map(x => Object.entries(x))
    .map(x => x.reduce(([l, r], x, i) =>
      i <= 4
        ? [[...l, x], r]
        : [l, [...r, x]],
      [[], []]))
    .map(x => x.map(x => Object.fromEntries(x)))
    .pop();
    
    
const [list1, list2] = partition(json.list);

console.log(list1);
console.log(list2);
```

```html
<script>
var json={
  list:{
    c1:"BTC",
    c2:"ETH",
    c3:"DOGE",
    c4:"LTC",
    c5:"BSV",
    c6:"XRB",
    c7:"SRB",
    c8:"WAVE",
    c9:"LINK",
    c10:"EOS"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. for...in

```js
var json = {
  list: {
    c1: "BTC",
    c2: "ETH",
    c3: "DOGE",
    c4: "LTC",
    c5: "BSV",
    c6: "XRB",
    c7: "SRB",
    c8: "WAVE",
    c9: "LINK",
    c10: "EOS"
  }
};

var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {};
var index = 0;

for (var propName in json.list) {
  if (index < 5) {
    obj1[propName] = json.list[propName];
  } else {
    obj2[propName] = json.list[propName];
  }
  index++;
}

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```

2. Object.entries(...)

```js
var json = {
  list: {
    c1: "BTC",
    c2: "ETH",
    c3: "DOGE",
    c4: "LTC",
    c5: "BSV",
    c6: "XRB",
    c7: "SRB",
    c8: "WAVE",
    c9: "LINK",
    c10: "EOS"
  }
};

var props = Object.entries(json.list);

var obj1 = props.slice(0, 5).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}, {});

var obj2 = props.slice(5, 10).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  obj[key] = value;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj2);
```